# Client (com.squareup.okhttp.OkhttpClient) in builder cannot be applied to (okhttp3.OkHttpClient)

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to use Retrofit2 and also Log errors in Full like its done in Retrofit1 using the

```
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
```

I'm am facing an error with .client( Okhttp client ); This is my dependencies below:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'

}
```

This is my java code:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);
```

I'm using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta3 and still having this issue. I can't move forward from here. Any help is appreciated. See image below:

[image: Okhttp client issue]

This is my import statements below:

[image]

Comment: use stable version of retrofit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its seems your import statement is from `okhttp`, 
Check out your import:-

must be `import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;`

or your retrofit import must be wrong.. it must be `retrofit2.Retrofit`

**[EDIT]**

*Seems there is problem with their beta versions, revert it to the stable version.*

Comment: ofcourse, i checked that already. it imports okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

Comment: Alright but your retrofit seems to be a `retrofit.Retrofit`, must be a `retrofit2.Retrofit`.

Comment: May be issues in Beta version

Comment: Thanks, this "retrofit2.Retrofit" solves it. I was importing the wrong thing :(

Comment: Hahaha... I blamed retrofit guys for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is no longer in beta for a while now. Use `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0` instead.